# Is there any legal obligation to banks to offer only one "purpose" field in online banking systems?

Tags: germany, banking, online

I have used numerous online banking interfaces in Germany for money transfer between accounts. While they can be quite different in terms of features such as auto-completion, storage of reusable transfer templates ("Überweisungsvorlagen"), etc., there appears to be one constant across all of them that keeps baffling me:

**There is only one field for the "intended purpose of the transfer" ("Verwendungszweck") rather than one 'public' and one 'private' one.**

This is baffling to me because the field evidently serves *two* conflicting purposes at a time:

- Identifying the transfer to the *recipient* of the money. (Usually, this happens by means of a cryptic customer ID or bill number, and appending something intelligible after that number has the risk that it breaks the recipient's automated processing of the payment, which may thus not be registered correctly in time.)
- Identifying the transfer to the *sender* of the money (e.g. when reviewing past transfers in bank statements). (Best done by a descriptive text that may include details the recipient of the money should not know about.)

The fact that none of the online banking systems I have used (or seen in use by close relatives and friends) featured such a distinction, though, makes me wonder: **Is there a legal requirement in Germany that obliges banks to offer or store data from *exactly one* such purpose field, leaving no leeway for banks to let customers save "private notes" for each transaction?**

(Of course, it *is* a possibility that my sample size of banks is too small in spite of everything.)

Comment: There's no reason why private notes would be a problem, it's just that no bank offers this feature. Private notes are not necessary to perform a transfer.

Comment: @amon: "Private notes are not necessary to perform a transfer." - neither are autocomplete in the money transfer form, transfer templates, or a custom date-based filtering of past transfers, though these are virtually ubiquitous. It may well be the case that simply "no bank offers this feature", even though it would be within regulations to do so.

Comment: @F-H It may be a good idea to present this suggestion to your bank. Maybe it leads to an alteration of the practice, maybe you get pointed to a reason why it does not work.

Comment: You can abuse the beneficiary name field for this purpose. The beneficiary name is only visible to you and the two banks involved and it doesn't have to match the account holder on the receiving side.